# I can't understand why map cause segmentation fault

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault, while-loop

I have a loop that does the following:

```
short fooID;
char line[256]
map<short,foo> foos;
set<short> barIDs;
while (fgets(line,256,file) != NULL){
  string line_copy = line;
  /*use token to split the line into several parameters which does not effect foo * bar*/
  string token = strtok(line,",");
  token = strtok(NULL,",");
  token = strtok(NULL,",");
  token = strtok(NULL,",");
  token = strtok(NULL,",");
  barID = short(atoi(token));
  foo * bar;
  bar = new foo;
  if(barIDs.find(barID) == barIDs.end()){
     barIDs.insert(barID);
     bar->setID(barID);
     this->foos[barID] = bar;
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get a segmentation fault when all the bars are loaded from the file.
the barID range is 1-1192.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

*The code above is only a typed summery of my actual code*

Comment: Show the declaration of `line`.

Comment: The part of code you shown seems to be innocent (modulo possible buffer overflow). Please show more code.

Comment: You were able to run this code!? You left out a semicolon, your fgets() is wrong and you don't have */ to close the comment.

Comment: @user: When asking for program crashes, we need an executable example that reproduces the error, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Johnsyweb, if you prefer to insult rather then help, well done, you have achieved that. I have a good reason to assume that you are a bunch of  intelligent guys who can understand from my question that my code does compile and the use  of Foo Bar notation means some general class and not th **actual** code. As for the remark, line is char* and not a string. (line_copy is a string)

Comment: In question about a problem in code **actual** code causing the problem is expected. Possibly minimal test case causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo * bar;
```

This creates a variable `bar` pointing to a random location in memory. You need to make it point to a valid object: `bar = new foo;` - and remember to delete it when you're done, iterate over your map and delete all the `foo`'s you added.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. All the declarations are legal (I'll update my code segment). I suspect that c++ is trying to add an empty line at the end or something

Comment: Show us real code. Your snippet won't compile - we can't spot problems in your code unless we *see* your code.

Comment: I don't need to delete them since I want to keep them throughout my run. Anyhow, it is not the source of my error (since bar is declared inside the loop which means I'm assigning new memory with each step).

Comment: You still need to do `new foo`

Comment: @user596691 -- your problem is *exactly* that you are not assigning any memory to `bar`. Your `bar` is a pointer, which needs an actual location to point *to*. You are just leaving it uninitialized. Read up on C++ basics if pointer is a foreign concept to you.

Comment: I have placed the new foo line and still I get an error. I'll have to assume that this has something to do with the way I create the bar class but I have no clue what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters )`  changes the contents of the `str` parameter (see [C++ Reference on strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)). Maybe you should replace `line` with `line_copy` since you're declaring it as `string line_copy = line;`?

Comment: line_copy is a string - not a char[]

Comment: I know, but I'm unsure what happens if 'line' becomes 'null' in the process of 'strtok' and then 'fgets' read something ... And, I was thinking in the direction of 'string::c_str'.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my guess is that you are crashing here:

```
barID = short(atoi(token));
```

If the last line of your data file has a line feed, then the last `fgets` read (before it returns NULL on EOF) will return a blank line. You are not checking for this condition. Similarly, you are not checking the result of `strtok` before passing it to `atoi`. And on the blank line, that result will be `NULL`. So `atoi` will crash.

That said, you are constantly changing the details so I have no way to know whether the described sequence of events has anything to do with your *real* code. This is not a great way to get help. I'd suggest you in the future provide an accurate code snippet (compilable is the best) and some details on the crash (normally it is not difficult to determine the location of the crash, at least).

Comment: I'm sorry about the details things. I'm trying to put all and only the relevant data into my question.   I thought that it might be a blank line issue but I don't have a blank line at the end of the file. I'll try and through stuff into a vector<vector<double>> and check it.

Comment: @user596691 - regardless of the blank line, why don't you add checking of the `strtok` result? It's unhealthy to assume a function will always succeed, especially one dealing with external data. Also, what is the crash location? It's the first thing to find out in case of a crash, but you are silent on this topic.

Comment: @user596691 - If you rewrite your code to use vector instead of map, you may well happen to mask the real problem, but it will be there still. I know, its a modern SW dev paradigm: make random changes until it compiles and appears to work. That's how the worst pieces of modern SW engineering were born. Please don't go this way unless your life depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a local foos:

```
map<short,foo> foos;
```

But later you use this->foos to store bar

```
this->foos[barID] = bar;
```

Also, the map is storing foo, not foo*